# Why z-index doesnt work?

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I have simple html and css code :

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="tip"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    display: block;
    width: 260px;
    min-height: 222px;
    background-color: #252525;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.tip {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    right: 11px;
    top: -5px;
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;

}
```

I just want to `.tip` block was under `.header` block.
But now it looks like this, although the z-index of `.tip` is less then z-index of `.header`:
[image]

This is what I want: [image]

For some reason, z-index doesn't work.
It's necessary for me to set z-index on `.header` block, because I have another blocks on page which have z-index too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the child of a parent element have a higher z-index than the parent element, remove the parent's z-index value.

```css
.header {
    display: block;
    width: 260px;
    min-height: 222px;
    background-color: #252525;
    position: relative;
    /*z-index: 5;*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.tip {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    right: 11px;
    top: -5px;
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="tip"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it works, but it's necessary for me to set z-index on .header block

Comment: @ZhekaVasil in that case, you probably can't do this with z-index alone. An element with a z-index starts a new stacking order, so a child element will always start at it's parent's stacking order. It might be possible to do whatever it is you're trying to do, but we'd need to see your complete code to try and find a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, now i get it

Answer (score 1):

try changing 1 to -1...and remove z-index: 5 in the first block (header); take a look of this part of the code:

```
.header {
    display: block;
    width: 260px;
    min-height: 222px;
    background-color: #252525;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.tip {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    right: 11px;
    top: -5px;
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;

}
```

Comment: It works great, but it's necessary for me to set z-index on .header block, because I have another blocks on page which have z-index too